# How to solve Data analysis questions using function

Tags: python, function

I have a basic function  Question in python.

You're planning a vacation, and you need to decide which city you want to visit. You have shortlisted four cities and identified the return flight cost, daily hotel cost, and weekly car rental cost. While renting a car, you need to pay for entire weeks, even if you return the car sooner.

```
City      Return Flight ($) Hotel per day ($)   Weekly Car Rental ($)
Paris        200                      20                   200
London       250                      30                   120
Dubai        370                      15                   80
Mumbai       450                      10                   70
```

Here are the questions

1. If you're planning a 1-week long trip, which city should you visit to spend the least amount of money?
2. If your total budget for the trip is $1000, which city should you visit to maximize the duration of
   your trip? Which city should you visit if you want to minimize the duration?

For Question1 I tried solving it this way

```
def vacation_plan(flight,Ht_per_day,car_rent):
    
    total_amount = flight+(Ht_per_day*7)+car_rent
    return total_amount

#lease amount
paris = vacation_plan(200,20,200)
London = vacation_plan(250,30,120)
Dubai = vacation_plan(370,15,80)
Mumbai = vacation_plan(450,10,70)
Least_amount = min(paris,London,Dubai,Mumbai)      
Least_amount
```

Question 2

I think I can use the `min` and `max` func to get that but I am sure of my answers

Comment: Did you notice, a week has 7 days?

Comment: @Dschoni I noticed that, I can simple multiply the days by 7 to correct that right..?

Comment: Yes. Now, it would be a good idea to have a data structure that makes any sense in holding your input. Next step would be to not hardcode the number of days, but have it as an input. Then you could iterate days having a loop etc. Right now, your question is not a programming question, but you need to understand the task that is given first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 2:

```
def vacation_plan(city,flight,Ht_per_day,car_rent):
    
    total_amount = flight+(Ht_per_day*7)+car_rent
    d[city]=total_amount
d={}
list1=list2=[]
vacation_plan("paris",200,20,200)
vacation_plan("london",250,30,120)
vacation_plan("dubai",370,15,80)
vacation_plan("mumbai",450,10,70)

for i in d:
    list1=list1+[i]
    list2=list2+[d[i]]
print(list1,list2)    

for i in range(0,len(list2)):
    if list2[i]==min(list2):
        print("to maximise duration go to", list1[i])
    elif list2[i]==max(list2):
        print("to minimise duration go to", list1[i])
```

output:

```
['paris', 'london', 'dubai', 'mumbai'] [540, 580, 555, 590]
to maximise duration go to paris
to minimise duration go to mumbai
```

I'm storing the names of the cities and their corresponding amounts in `list1` and `list2`.
The `max()` and `min()` functions are then used to find the required amounts and the corresponding cities.

Answer (score 0):

I  was able to find a way to answer the above question

Answer to Question 1

1.

```
    def cost_of_vacation(header,values):
    vacation_plan = {}
    for city,cost in zip(header,values):
        vacation_plan[city]=cost
    return vacation_plan
    
city,values =  ['paris','London','Dubai','Mumbai'],[[200,20,200],[250,30,120],[370,15,80],[450,10,70]] 
a_day_vacation = cost_of_vacation(city,values)


def least_expensive_city(vacation,days):
    result = {}
    for key, value in vacation.items():
        result[key]=sum(value)*days
        print(result)
    max_city = min(result, key=result.get)
    return max_city
city = least_expensive_city(a_day_vacation,7)
print('The city with least is {}'.format(city))
```

`Output: The city with least is London`

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to question 1**
import math
def expenditure(return_flight_cost, hotel_perday, car_rent, number_of_days):
total_flight_cost = 2 * return_flight_cost
hotel_rent = hotel_perday * number_of_days
total_expense = total_flight_cost + hotel_rent + car_rent
math.ceil(total_expense)
return total_expense

```
paris = expenditure(200, 20, 200, 4)
london = expenditure(250, 30, 120,)
dubai = expenditure(370, 15, 80)
mumbai = expenditure(450, 10, 70)

if paris < london:
    if paris < dubai:
        if paris < mumbai:
            print("Paris is the cheapest.")
        else:
            print("Mumbai is the cheapest.")
    elif dubai < mumbai:
        print("Dubai is the cheapest.")
    else:
        print("Mumbai is the cheapest.")
elif london < dubai:
    if london < mumbai:
        print("London is the cheapest.")
```

''' i have done in this way. is this correct?'''

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32788810)

Answer (score 0):

For Question 1:

```
Paris={
    'Return_flight':200,
    'Hotel_per_day':20,
    'Weekly_car_rental':200,
    'City':'Paris'
}
London={
    'Return_flight':250,
    'Hotel_per_day':30,
    'Weekly_car_rental':120,
    'City':'London'
}
Dubai={
    'Return_flight':370,
    'Hotel_per_day':15,
    'Weekly_car_rental':80,
    'City':'Dubai'
}
Mumbai={
    'Return_flight':450,
    'Hotel_per_day':10,
    'Weekly_car_rental':70,
    'City':'Mumbai'
}

def cost_of_trip(City,Trip_duration):
    car_rent_duration=math.ceil(Trip_duration/7) #since car rental is weekly basis
    total_trip_cost=City['Return_flight']+City['Hotel_per_day']*Trip_duration+car_rent_duration*City['Weekly_car_rental']
    
    print("Total cost for {} trip for {} days is:{}".format(City['City'],Trip_duration,total_trip_cost))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def cost_of_trip(flight_cost, hotel_rate, car_rental_rate, duration=int(input("Duration of vacation in days: "))):    
    if duration <= 7:    
        city_cost = flight_cost + hotel_rate*duration + car_rental_rate    
    else:    
        city_cost = flight_cost + hotel_rate*duration + (2*car_rental_rate)     
    return city_cost     


city_cost_paris = cost_of_trip(200, 20, 200)     
print(city_cost_paris)    
city_cost_london = cost_of_trip(250, 30, 120)     
print(city_cost_london)    
city_cost_dubai = cost_of_trip(370, 15, 80)    
print(city_cost_dubai)     
city_cost_mumbai = cost_of_trip(450, 10, 70)     
print(city_cost_mumbai)     

A = dict(Paris=city_cost_paris, London=city_cost_london, Dubai=city_cost_dubai, Mumbai=city_cost_mumbai)     
print("the cost for respective destination is", A)      

least_cost = min(A, key=A.get)      
print(f'The destination that will cost least is {least_cost}')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).